# Generate MySQL/MariaDB SSL certificates from my wildcard certificate (*.mycompany.com)

Tags: mysql, mariadb, ssl, certificate

I'm configuring a series of MariaDB servers with SSL protection. I was able to do it creating different self-signed certificates, as everybody can do just following some of the multiple tutorials you can find around the Internet.

However I was wondering if it's possible to use our wildcard certificate (the one that we use for our https servers) to generate the same files.

The self-signed procedure runs at follows

1. Generate root CA
2. Generate the server key
3. Generate the x509 cert **signed with the CA key**
4. Generate the client key
5. Generate the x509 cert **signed with the CA key**

From my Cert provider I got:

1. certificate.crt
2. certificate.key
3. certificate.ca.crt

Obviously, I'm missing the CA key

Can I use this files to generate the server and client certs?

--
Add here the openssl command I use to generate the self signed certs

````
#Generate certificates
#Generate root-CA
openssl genrsa 2048 > ca-key.pem
openssl req -new -x509 -nodes -days 3600 -key ca-key.pem -out ca-cert.pem -subj "/C=XX/ST=XXXXXX/CN=BI-XXXXXX"

# server key
openssl req -newkey rsa:2048 -days 3600 -nodes -keyout server-key.pem -out server-req.pem -subj "/C=XX/ST=XXXXXXX/CN=BI-XXXXXXX-Server"
openssl rsa -in server-key.pem -out server-key.pem
openssl x509 -req -in server-req.pem -days 3600 -CA ca-cert.pem -CAkey ca-key.pem -set_serial 01 -out server-cert.pem

# client key
openssl req -newkey rsa:2048 -days 3600 -nodes -keyout client-key.pem -out client-req.pem -subj "/C=XX/ST=XXXXXXXX/CN=BI-XXXXXXXX-Client"
openssl rsa -in client-key.pem -out client-key.pem
openssl x509 -req -in client-req.pem -days 3600 -CA ca-cert.pem -CAkey ca-key.pem -set_serial 01 -out client-cert.pem```
````

Comment: Not sure what you're asking. How to sign a server certificate without the CA key? You can't, obviously.

Comment: @mustaccio Hi, what I want to achieve (if possible) is generate my server and client certificates, but not from a selfsigned root-CA. I want to use my wildcard certificates so certificates are "trustable"